# Is it possible for a function to be continuous at a point if the function is not defined either to the left or right of that point?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Take for example the function $f:[0,\infty) \to \Bbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is this function continuous at $x=0$?

For it to be continuous we look for $$\lim _{x\to0} f(x)$$ and we say it is continuous if that limit is $f(0)=0$ but is $$\lim _{x\to 0} \sqrt x=0$$ I believe it is but can't we say if this limit exists then the left hand limit and right hand limit both exist and are equal but here the left hand limit does not exist since it is not in the domain of $f$ when approaching from the left?

Could anyone clear up the confusion?

Comment: In such cases the phrases "left continuity" or "right continuity" in real analysis may help avoid confusion.  Continuity can be defined in a more general topological setting, where "left" and "right" are meaningless, and so the confusion doesn't arise because of the more general definition in terms of deleted open neighborhoods.

Comment: The definitions that mathematicians use in regard to all this are not the same as what you usually find in calculus books. I'd say yes, $\sqrt x$ is continuous at the origin, although some calculus books may disagree.

Comment: Well, to by a fifth person with a sixth opinion I'd say if a function isn't defined to the left of a point and "to the left of the point" is then no, it isn't continuous but if "to the left" isn't, it is.  In other words, if it's defined on the domain space yes, if not,no.  Your function is continuous if the domain space is considered to only be the non-negatives.  It isn't if the domain space is considered to be the reals.  Example all functions defined only on the natural numbers are cont.  if N is seen as universal space.  None are if N is seen as a subset of R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very good question. The answer is that it depends on exactly how continuity is defined. Some people define it for real functions such that it must be defined on an open interval around the point, otherwise it is considered non-continuous. But a more general definition is:
$\def\wi{\subseteq}$

> Given any metric spaces $S,T$, a function $f : S \to T$ is **continuous** at $x \in S$ iff, for any open set $B \wi T$ such that $f(x) \in B$, for some open set $A \wi S$ with $x \in A$ we have $Im_f(A) \wi B$.

Note that under this definition we would consider the square-root function on the non-negative reals to be continuous at $0$. Issues of left-continuity and right-continuity don't matter because they are irrelevant in the metric space sense.

Comment: And note that this definition extends with no change to general topological spaces without a metric. This is why we often use this definition now.

Answer (score 3):

In general topology $f:[0,\infty) \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is a continuous function, the point outside the domain $[0,\infty)$ does not affect the continuity of $f$ in any way.

However, in pre-calculus the situation is more complicated. One often sees the definition of continuity as a function satisfying the following conditions:

> 1. $f(x_0)$ exists.
> 2. $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ exists
> 3. The two are equal

The problem often lies with 2, since students are taught that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ exists *iff* $\lim_{x\to x_0^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0^-} f(x)$ exists - and in this case $\lim_{x\to x_0^-} f(x)$ doesn't.

I'd say that it depends on the convention you are using and how you are taught in the class. If it's a metric space or topology class then yes, it is continuous. However, if you are in an elementary calculus class and your teachers are somewhat unreasonable, then you might very well lose some points for saying that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Yup I remember noticing this discrepancy when I was an undergraduate taking the first calculus class.