# Does continuity of $f$ at a point require the existence of $f$ in a neighbourhood of that point?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, neighbourhood

The title is self explanatory, does continuity of $f$ at a point require the existence of $f$ in a neighbourhood of that point?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit the body of the question so that it contains the question itself.

Comment: What is really you question? Is it “Does continuity of $f$ at a point require the existence of $f$ in a neighbourhood of that point?” Or is it “Is this derivative continue at $(0,0)$?”

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos my question is the first, the other one is just an example, should I remove it?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726025/is-it-possible-for-a-function-to-be-continuous-at-a-point-if-the-function-is-not)?

Comment: I think that you should delete it. Otherwise, your question might get deleted, for being several questions posted as a single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the only thing that it is required about the point $p$ in order to say that a function $f\colon D\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is continuous at $p$ is is an accumulation point of $D$ which belongs to $D$. In other words, $p\in D$ and every neighbourhood contains some point of $D$ other than $p$. So, in particular, no, $f$ doesn't have to be defined on a neighbourhood of $p$.